# how to move ssh-key related files to another directory?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, ssh-keys, fish, dotfiles

i've been trying to clean up my root directory so that it isn't clustered with random dotfiles.
nonetheless, on setting up the *ssh-key* i came to a dead-end, where i wouldn't find a way to migrate `known_hosts` file to the other direction (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/config`).

i used this command to generate my *ssh-key*:

```
mkdir -p $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my@email.com" -f $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/id_ed25519
```

but yet i need to create a `~/.ssh/config` file to point at my `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/config` file, which is frustrating because i want to get rid of the `~/.ssh` directory

i used several approaches one of them was to set an env var `SSH_CONFIG` to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/config` but that didn't work either

**⚠️ i'm using macOS and fish shell to prevent confusion**

this is the $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/ directory structure:

```
config
id_ed25519
id_ed25519.pub
known_hosts #this file is ignored as ssh expects its in ~/.ssh/
```

this is the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/config` file:

```yaml
GlobalKnownHostsFile $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/known_hosts #this doesn't help either 
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/id_ed25519
```

and the current fix that is working, is only creating a `.ssh/config` with the value `UserKnownHostsFile $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/known_hosts`, which makes my whole migration of the files pointless.

`.ssh/config` file:

```yaml
UserKnownHostsFile $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/known_hosts
```

is there something that i'm missing?

how can i fix this?

or is there a better way of organising one selfs root folder?

i tried to set the env var `SSH_CONFIG` but it seems to ignore it:

```bash
set -Ux SSH_CONFIG ~/.config/ssh/config #fish syntax, it's the same as: export SSH_CONFIG="$HOME/.config/ssh/config"
```

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i can't delete it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH has no support for $XDG_CONFIG_HOME. This has been asked for years ago and rejected.

Unfortunately the bug tracker is now login-only, so here's an archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20190925004614/https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2050

And here's the maintainer's justification:

> No.

> OpenSSH (and it's ancestor ssh-1.x) have a 17 year history of using ~/.ssh. This location is baked into innumerable users' brains, millions of happily working configurations and countless tools.

> Changing the location of our configuration would require a very strong justification and following a trend of desktop applications (of which OpenSSH is not) is not sufficient.

So you'll either have to make a symlink or alias all ssh tools to read a different config file. Unfortunately, if you give `-F /path/to/config`:

> If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored

So this isn't a great idea either. My advice is to simply live with the directory.